# fabric.js path objects are offset when migrating from 1.5.0 to 1.7.3

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am now using fabric.js 1.7.3 from 1.5.0 because I need the loadSVGFromString function.
But some of my Path objects are now horizontally offset, even with the exact same code in my app.
I have tried replicated with a very simple demo but that fails.
Any idea which fabric.js change could cause this?
I looked through the release notes without finding the answer.

Comment: can you show some code? how much are offseted?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue was with the strokeWidth option. It appears that fabricjs 1.7.3 does not draw the path when it is a string instead of a number, whereas 1.5.0 does.
Here is an example:

```js
  fc = new fabric.Canvas('canvas')
  let path = 'M100,100 L150,100 A20,20,0,0,0,170,80 L170,50 A20,20,0,0,1,190,30 L240,30'
  let line = new fabric.Path(path, { stroke: 'green', strokeWidth: '1', fill: '' })
  fc.add(line)
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

This does show a green path. If you change to fabric 1.7.3 the green line does not show anymore. 
It 'reappears' if you change to let line = new fabric.Path(path, { stroke: 'green', strokeWidth: 1, fill: '' })

Comment: if this is true we could change this answer in something usefull for everyone with proper explanation. can you post a code sample of what was failing?